# how to get all the elements of a html table with pagination using selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a webpage with a table. The table has pagination with 7 entries per page. I want to get access to all the elements of the table.

```
table_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
for tr in table_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
    print tr.text
```

With the above code, I am able to get the elements in the first page only but not the subsequent pages of the same table. How can I get all the elements?

[sample image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6158V.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534584/navigating-pagination-with-selenium

Comment: if you can, give the adresse of the page

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop outside of the code you provided that clicks the next page link (or the equivalent) until the next page link no longer exists. Without any HTML, we can't provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I have added the image of the table. I want to know if there is a way other than looping by simulating clicking on the next button. Currently I am searching in the table instead of looping. I want to know if there is a way to get all the entries of the table withpot iterating.

Comment: Selenium can only see what is on the current page. You won't be able to see what's on the next page of the table until you click next. There is an outside chance that the data is already in the page and is only exposed when the user clicks Next but that is highly unlikely. One way to find out is to navigate to the next page, find some unique data in the page, page back to the first page, and then search the HTML source of the page for the data you found on page 2.